# Arranging distinct objects into different boxes

Tags: combinatorics

How would you arrange, let's say n different objects into r different groups. Is there some separate formula for calculating this?

I found this formula in a book, but I don't understand it

$r^n - rC_1*[(r-1)^n] + rC_2[(r-2)^n] - \cdots$

Also why the alternating plus minus signs?

Comment: @user32304 I have added TeX code to this to make it look nicer. To do this I simply typed 

\$r^n - rC_1*[(r-1)^n] + rC_2[(r-2)^n] - \cdots\$ 

to obtain $r^n - rC_1*[(r-1)^n] + rC_2[(r-2)^n] - \cdots$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with latex

Comment: @user34304 Can I ask from which book this is?

Comment: @user34304 That's okay. If you right click on the formula above, then click Show Math As >> Tex Commands, you can see the TeX that is required to create the "nice" version. Just put that code between \$ \$ and you have it. You can do this with any of the questions and answers on here.

Comment: Perhaps this is a simplified reference to stirlings numbers of second kind.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want each group to have at least one item. If you remove this last requirement, then you have $r^n$ ways. But this also counts situations in which one group does not have any items, so we remove those:

$$ r^n - \binom{r}{1}(r-1)^n$$

But now we're double counting situations where *two* groups do not have items, so we add those back:

$$ r^n - \binom{r}{1}(r-1)^n + \binom{r}{2}(r-2)^n $$

and so on.

This is the complementary form of the inclusion-exclusion principle. Let $A_i$ be the situations in which group $i$ does not have any items, and let $S$ the set of all possible situations. Then

$$ \biggl|S - \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\biggr| = \left| S \right| - \sum_{i=1}^n\left|A_i\right|\; + \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} \left|A_i\cap A_j\right| 
- \ldots + (-1)^{n} \left|A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n\right| $$

Answer (score 1):

This is because of [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html).